# "SSH server" in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, remote

I have some command-line commands to execute on a Windows machine.  The programs I need to run are only available on Windows.

Is there a way to easily to do something like I would do with SSH?  Example of what I mean:

```
ssh username@windows-box.mycompany.com "remote command to execute"
```

...or do I have to Remote Desktop just to do this?  (I'd like to run the commands programmatically from another computer rather than running them by hand.)

Comment: So, am I correct in reading between the lines that this "other computer" is *not* running windows, and that this is the reason you want/need to execute these commands remotely?

Comment: @SamB:  Yes, that's correct.  I'm using Ubuntu on my main machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach, of course, is to actually run an SSH server on the windows box.  But a more Windows-focused solution is a tool from the SysInternals folks (now part of Microsoft) called [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which is designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: But PsExec only runs on *Windows* systems, right?

Comment: @SamB Yes. It's actually used to run commands with (super-)elevated privileges, including as the SYSTEM account (not only Administrator).

Answer (score 2):

You need a SSH server running on windows. like http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm

There isnt any installed by default, And I have been using this for some time. it is good

Comment: Remark, this solution does not support key authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of good experience installing cygwin and its sshd port.  There are wrappers which will turn it into a windows service, and you get the bash shell as an extra.

http://chinese-watercolor.com/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html is a decent starting point, you can evaluate if it is what you want.

Comment: Agreed, cygwin + ssh is nice and easy, and you get a conveniently unix-like shell and environment to run your programs from.  If you like ssh, you probably already know Unix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the freesshd server from [fresshd.com](http://www.freesshd.com/). It does work great, you will set-up the server in seconds :)

Comment: This looks as a nice solution but, the forum is down (cannot post) and it looks that it doesn't allow domain logins.

Comment: Also, this is only 'free', meaning that every time you do a SSH it will display you a login message asking you to register(buy) it, you have to wait 5+ seconds to be able to continue.

Comment: Remark, this is a slow SSH server.

Comment: I tried `freesshd` - what you get is a login into a windows shell (cmd.exe?) with a fixed width that does not adapt to your terminal client, i.e. you get annoying line breaks mid-screen. Also, it's nowhere near a `bash` shell, so I figured, if I want a really usable ssh login into my windows box, I'll do it using `cygwin`, which I've done before. Granted, cygwin is a bit like an os inside the os, but it does make windows usable for a (unix) cmd line user.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2015-06-02, [Microsoft has announced upcoming support for SSH](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/looking_forward_microsoft__support_for_secure_shell_ssh1/archive/2015/06/02/managing-looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Cygwin** has a ssh server, howtogeek has a simple guide you can follow
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Answer (score -1):

you can install an SSH server on your Windows machines, or you can turn on Terminal services on windows (check your documentation), and then use Perl(or Python) to do a telnet to the server to execute your commands. See [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm)(Perl) for examples of connecting through telnet

Comment: Well, it's all fine and dandy to say RTFM, but that would be easier if we could *find* said manual... any tips, such as the name of page and maybe an MSDN/Technet link -- especially now that it seems like MS may have finally learned the value of an URL?

Comment: Also, isn't there some registry change needed to get it let you have more than one logged-in session at the same time on anything less than Server? I doubt MS would want to make the docs for that easy to find, assuming that there are any docs for that...